# Page/2/ giving 404 when query is added

Tags: php, wp-query, pages, pagination, navigation

If I do a search `example.com/?s=london` with no `wp_query` I get results and I can change pages. But if I add a `wp_query` and do the same search `example.com/?s=london` if I click to page 2 `example.com/page/2/?s=london`  I get a 404. Also with a `wp_query` added if I do a blank search and change pages `example.com/page/2/?s=` i dont get 404. Its seems that the searched word is doing it but I'm not sure why. Ive tried changing my permalinks so they update but still get the same. This is the `wp_query` I'm using so you can see.

```
    <?php

     $args_a = array(
        'post_type'  => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'CurrentLocation',
                'value'   => $searchm,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'AreaLookingFor',
                'value'   => $areaihave,
                'type'    => '',
                'compare' => '=',
                    ),               
        ),
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
    );

    $query_a = new WP_Query( $args_a ); ?>

    <?php if ( $query_a->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php while ( $query_a->have_posts() ) : $query_a->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' );      
     endwhile; ?>  

   next_posts_link( 'Next', $query_a->max_num_pages ); 
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'No homes matched your criteria' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Tried that answer above it doesn't work

Comment: whether or not you get a 404 is dependent on the results of the *main query*, whatever queries you run in the template are unrelated.